# How to push multiple view controllers into UINavigation but only show animation once?

Tags: ios

Actually, I know how to push multiple viewControllers. My question focus on the animation.In a UINavigationcontroller, I try to push two viewControllers. And I cancel the animation of the first push. However, in iPhone 6, iOS9.0 simulator, and iphone6 plus iOS9.0 real device, two animations are visible... My code is following:

```
UINavigationController *a = (UINavigationController *)(self.tabBarController.selectedViewController);
Second11ViewController *view11 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second1"];
Second22ViewController *view22 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second2"];
view11.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
view22.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
[a pushViewController:view11 animated:NO];
[a pushViewController:view22 animated:YES];
```

Any trick to do this. I want to show animation exactly once, like I just push one viewController (actually two)..

Comment: Did your code with animated yes/ no work ?

Comment: @GeneratorOfOne Yeah.. it confuses me.. I see the screen slide left twice quickly. But in iPhone 5 iOS 7 only once . is it something about to do with iPhone system performance between different devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
[a setViewControllers:@[view11, view22] animated:YES];
```

Hope this would be help to you :)

Exactly, view11 will not be loaded before you pop out view22.

Answer (score -1):

You can push the view controller you want to be on screen at the end and animate it. For adding the others into the navigation stack try to play around with `self.navigationController.viewControllers`in the `viewDidLoad` of the finally displayed view controller.

In your code:

```
UINavigationController *a = (UINavigationController *)self.tabBarController.selectedViewController;
Second11ViewController *view11 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second1"];
Second22ViewController *view22 = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second2"];
view11.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
view22.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

[a pushViewController:view22 animated:YES];
```

And in `Second22ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```
NSMutableArray *viewControllers = self.navigationController.viewControllers.mutableCopy;
id lastViewController = [viewControllers lastObject];
[viewControllers removeLastObject];
[viewControllers addObject:/*an instance of the view controller in between*/];
[viewControllers addObject:lastViewController];
self.navigationController.viewControllers = viewControllers.copy;
```

But be careful:
After you go back in the navigation (tap back button) from `Second22ViewController`, the `viewDidLoad` of `Second11ViewController` will be invoked, therefore care about infinite loops (I mean do not add a view controller in between with the same type of the finally visible one).

Comment: Please provide comments for your down votes, so I do not make the same mistake again.